# Search for a user by their first name with a Wordpress Multi Site setup

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to search for users by "first name" or "last name" with a Wordpress Multisite configuration?

I'd like to list all users who have the first name "Adam"

Comment: Do you know how to do it on a single site?

Comment: on a single site, the search functions in a different way, you can search by first name, last name etc. By default this isn't possible on Multisite, so I'd like to know any solutions to this.

Comment: Which interface are you using for searching?

Comment: Using the Network Admin user search. (It looks the same as the regular wordpress user search, but functions differently) /wp-admin/network/users.php

Answer (score 0):

To search for users using Wordpress Multisite, you need to use wildcard searches.

e.g

```
*@hotmail.com
adam*
```